# Is it possible to convert from Cartesian (x,y,z) to Spherical with 3 points in Python?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am actually trying to get rotation(x,y,z) with 3 points in Python.
I think converting from Cartesian (x,y,z) to Spherical is the best way to solve it.
However, I do not know how to calculate with 3 points.

```
import numpy as np

#3 vertex points
p1=[x1,y1,z1]
p2=[x2,y2,z2]
p3=[x3,y3,z3]

def cart2sph(x,y,z): #Converting from Cartesian to Spherical
    X_Y = x**2 + y**2
    r = m.sqrt(X_Y + z**2)         
    v = m.atan2(m.sqrt(X_Y),z)
    z = m.atan2(y,x) 
    return r,z ,v
```

Comment: What do you mean with get rotation? It seems your function is transfroming properly from cartesians to cylindrical. What is the output do you expect?

Comment: this seems like a math question not anything particularly language specific, it's just some formula you need to find, if you don't know it, you can surely look it up on google or maybe ask in the math stackexchange forum

Comment: I am sorry I could not explain in detail. I just want to get angle (as x,y rotation value) with 3 points in 3d space. carteresians to cylindrical fomula uses one vertex point, so I thought I can modify with it to find angle with 3points.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a math stack exchange type of question but nonetheless here is the code, for the explanation you are going to have to search it up or ask on math stackexchange.

Resource used for formula: [Cartesian to Spherical coordinates Calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1359533867)

```py
import math

def cart2sph(x, y, z):
    r = math.hypot(x, y, z)
    t = math.atan2(y, x)
    z = math.atan2(math.hypot(x, y), z)
    return r, t, z
```